# Property '...' does not exist on type 'Api<BaseQueryFn<string | FetchArgs, unknown, FetchBaseQueryError, {}, FetchBaseQueryMeta> redux-tookit

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-redux, redux-toolkit

```
import { createApi, fetchBaseQuery } from "@reduxjs/toolkit/query/react"
import { JobForm, Job } from "../types/JobsTypes"

export const createJobApis = createApi({
    reducerPath: "createJobApi",
    baseQuery: fetchBaseQuery({
        baseUrl: "http://localhost:8000/api/v1/jobs",
        prepareHeaders: (headers) => {
            headers.set("Content-Type", "application/json")
            headers.set("accept", "application/json")
            return headers
        },
    }),
    endpoints: (build) => ({
        getAll: build.query<Job, void>({ query: () => "/" }),
        created: build.mutation({
            query: (body: JobForm) => ({
                url: "/",
                method: "post",
                body,
            }),
        }),
    }),
})

export const { useCreatedMutation, useGetAllQuery } = createJobApis
console.log(useCreatedMutation)
```

Typescript says property does not exist on both the useCreatedMutation and useGetAllQuery on hover and has a type of any, but the console log returns a function and I tried it and it works and I get no error in the console, just no type support and a red underline on both exports

Comment: What version of TS are you using? You need at least 4.1 for this to work.

Comment: I installed it with the CRA template so version 4.5.4, but installed the redux-toolkit later

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? I'm on typescript 4.3.5 and getting the same error.

Comment: No, I just started a new project and it started working fine